# jasmine mocking angular $http - Error: describe does not expect a done parameter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, mocking, jasmine

I have an angular factory like this:

```
.factory('widgetFactory', ['$http', function($http){
  function getWidgets(){
    return $http.get('http://example.com/api/widgets/')
     .then(function(response){
        return response;
     });
  }
  return {
    getWidgets:getWidgets
  };
}])
```

And I have the following jasmine test:

```
describe('widgetFactory', function ($q) {
  var mockHttp,
  fakeResponse = 'response'
  beforeEach(function() {

    mockHttp = {
      get: jasmine.createSpy('get spy').and.callFake(function () {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        deferred.resolve(fakeResponse);
        return deferred.promise;
      })
    };

    module(function ($provide) {
      $provide.value('$http', mockHttp);
    });

  });

  it('should call api when getWidgets is called', inject(function (widgetFactory) {
    var result;
    widgetFactory.getWidgets().then(function(response){
      result = response;
    });
    expect(mockHttp.post).toHaveBeenCalledWith('http://example.com/api/widgets/');
    expect(result).toBe(fakeResponse);
  }));
});
```

But I get the following error: **describe does not expect a done parameter**

I think it may be to do with how I'm using $q in my test (other examples I've seen have `inject(function($q){ ...` inside the `beforeEach`, but I can't due to my use of `module` inside `beforeEach` as this then gives me the following error: Injector already created, can not register a module!)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You can't inject in describe method. Here I've reworked your version to use `ngMock` and get rid of mockHttp. I hope it explains a little bit how `ngMock` works

```
describe('widgetFactory', function () {
  var mockHttp,
  fakeResponse = 'response',
  getWidgetsDefer,
  getWidgetsPromise,
  $httpBackend,
  widgetFactory,
  $q;

  beforeEach(module('plunker'));

  beforeEach(inject(function($injector) {
    $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');
    $q = $injector.get('$q');
    widgetFactory = $injector.get('widgetFactory');
  }));

  beforeEach(function() {
    getWidgetsDefer = $q.defer();

    $httpBackend.when('GET', 'http://example.com/api/widgets/')
      .respond(getWidgetsDefer);

    getWidgetsPromise = widgetFactory.getWidgets();
  });

   afterEach(function() {
     $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
     $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
   });

  it('should call api when getWidgets is called', inject(function (widgetFactory) {
    expect($httpBackend.flush).not.toThrow();
  }));
});
```

You can find plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/pOafA5biXH0htSyrEa7F?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

'done' function is the argument that is expected in Jasmine blocks, but not in `describe`, that's the meaning of the error. Angular services can't be injected without `inject` wrapper because Jasmine is unaware of them, and the problem can't be solved just by ignoring this fact.

`angular.mock.module` is able to mock services [with object argument](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/function/angular.mock.module#usage), there's no need to re-invent the wheel.

Unfortunately, mocked services are meant to be self-contained, and it won't solve the problem with `$q`, so it has to be injected in addition after `module`:

```
  var $q;
  beforeEach(function() {

    module({
      $http: { ... }
    });

    inject(function (_$q_) {
      $q = _$q_;
    });
  })
```

Fortunately, ngMock provides [$httpBackend mock](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend), so mocking `$http` is pointless. In fact, real request shouldn't (and can't) be performed with ngMock. The spec for widget service becomes as slim as that:

```
widgetFactory.getWidgets();
$httpBackend.expect('GET', 'http://example.com/api/widgets/').respond(fakeResponse);
expect($httpBackend.flush).not.toThrow();
```

Notice that it doesn't matter if the request was mocked before or after `$http.get` call, the requests are solved when `$httpBackend.flush()` is called. And `fakeResponse === fakeResponse` check can be safely skipped as well.